# Unfortunately this model ..... to be the most unpopular the company had ever produced

Tags: exam-questions

Which option fits best for the following question.

> Unfortunately this model  ..... to be the most unpopular the company
>   had ever produced.
>
> A.Developed
>
> B.Marketed
>
> C.Turned
>
> D.Proved

---

For me the option C looks fine but the answer is D.Is the given answer correct? Prove reminds me of scientific theories whereas something can turn to be in unexpected end.

and how about

> Unfortunately this model  turn out to be the most unpopular the
>   company had ever produced

Is this sentence sound ok?

Answer (score 2):

Your variant with "*turned out*" is actually good and fits well.  There is, however, a distinct difference between "*turned*" and "*turned out*", making the former not a good choice in the original sentence.

The answer "proved" is the most fitting from the given choices.

> Unfortunately this model ***proved*** to be the most unpopular the company had ever produced.

The word "*developed*" doesn't fit supposedly because a "model" *does not develop* by itself once it goes into production.  (It can develop something else, like a cult following, and the sentence does not have an object suitable for that verb.)

The word "*marketed*" doesn't fit because the verb "market" means the activity of humans related to a "model", but not of the model itself.

The word "*turned*" doesn't fit because without the preposition "*out*" it has a different meaning than with it.

The word "*proved*" is the most suitable because that's an action the model *can* take after it is produced.